# неправильно работает логическая операция ИЛИ

Tags: c++, if, логические-выражения

У меня возникла проблема с использованием операции ИЛИ
в условном операторе if. Задача следующая: "Напишите программу,
которая запрашивает целое число и печатает английское порядковое
числительное. Общее правило: если число заканчивается на 1, ставят
суффикс “st”, если на 2 — “nd”, если на 3 — “rd”, а в остальных
случаях — “th”. Исключение составляют числа, которые оканчиваются на
11, 12 и 13. Для них используют суффикс “th”." Тема посвящена
условным операторам, поэтому я решил использовать If и else if для
решения задачи. Но при попытке ввести исключение в первую if, код
сломался и стал выдавать все вводимые числа с суффиксом th.

```
    int x;
    string suf;
    cin>>x;
    int mod10=abs(x%10),mod100=abs(x%100);
    if (mod100==11||12||13){
        suf="th";
    }
    else if (mod10==4){
        suf="st";
        }
    cout<<abs(x)<<suf<<endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

Ваше "сравнение"

```
if (mod100==11||12||13){
```

на самом деле означает

```
if (((mod100==11)||(12))||(13)){
```

т.е. `mod100` никогда не сравнивается ни с 12, ни с 13. А поскольку при приведении к булеву типу вы получаете для ненулевых значений `true`, то

```
if (((mod100==11)||(true))||(true)){
```

всегда вычисляется как `true`.

Программист не должен быть ленивым :), пишите ясно

```
if (mod100==11||mod100==12||mod100==13){
```

или

```
if (mod100>=11 && mod100<=13){
```